# Search for uncomented string in all files on Linux / Sublime

Tags: linux, replace, find, sublimetext2

I have to remove all font-family CSS delcarations from a huge project, there are inline CSS, SASS and regular CSS files.

I started using grep to comment out these lines, as I feel it will be useful to know what font was defined.

The way I do this is I search in Sublime for `font-family:` and use grep to replace the strings I find in sublime, example: replacing `font-family: Arial;` with `/* font-family: Arial; */`.

There are bout 4000 font-family declarations in the entire website, my plan is to use grep to replace all the `font-family:` declarations I find in the first few hundred find lines in Sublime, then search again to find only the ones that have not been commented.

Like this, grep will handle most occurrences, and the more I repeat this process the fewer un-commented font declarations will be.

Problem is I need to use sublime or linux to search for all `font-family:` declarations that are not commented. Or in other words to find all files that contain this string without a /* before it.

Any ideas? Or alternative solutions?

This is the grep command I use in case anyone needs it:

```
grep -rli 'font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;' * | xargs -i@ sed -i 's/font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;/\/* font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; *\//g' @
```

Comment: It would help if you posted a few of the lines you want to change.

Comment: For example, I want to find all "font-family:" but ignore any results that are preceded by a comment tag, ignore all like this: "/* font-family:".

So finding all un-commented font-family declaration.

Comment: I'm checking out Sublime regular expressions, will post back if I find a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Sublime Text 2, CTRL+SHIFT+F then checked the "regular expression" button next to the case sensitive button and used this regular expression:

https://regex101.com/r/pU0bB3/2

I posted a separate regex question that got [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34354806/regular-expression-search-in-sublime-for-all-font-family-not-preceded-by-an-ope?noredirect=1#comment56452375_34354806).

Answer (score 0):

To exclude the matches of font-family that are already commented out, you can use a negative lookbehind (see for example http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). I.e. you would search for

```
(?<!/\*)font-family\s*:[^;]+;
```

In addition, there are probably easier tools to do find and replace stuff. For example in notepad++, press "Strg+F", then select the tab "Find in files", select the directory where you want to replace stuff, select the toogle-button "Regular expressions" and for "Find what:" type in

```
(?<!/\*)font-family\s*:[^;]+;
```

and for "Replace with:" type in

```
/*$0*/
```

and say replace in files. Hope that helps.

Comment: this: `^(?:(?!/\*).)*\s*font-family:.*` seems to work :)