# Regular Expression search in Sublime for all font-family: not preceded by an opening comment

Tags: css, regex, sublimetext2

I have to remove a lot of `font-family:` declarations from my website, they are hundreds and I have replaced most of them with the same line, only commented (ex: `/* font-family: "Segoe UI","Helvetica","Arial"; */`).

Now, if I could only search for the un-commented ones to find the few that are left. My first atempt clearly demonstrates I do not fully understand regular expressions:

```
^(?!(?:/*)).*\s*."font-family:"."*"
```

The syntax is Boost (but only a subpart of it, as the replacement is PCRE-style).

Comment: If you are using Find and Replace, the regex syntax is Boost (but only a subpart of it, as the replacement is PCRE-style).

Comment: Ok, thanks :) editing question.

Comment: So, you just want to keep `/*...*/` comments and remove `font-family: "..","...";` everywhere else?

Comment: I want to not find the commented ones, and wrap the rest in comment tags, but a replace all is not needed, simply finding them is enough, there are not too many left. This somewhat works: ^(?!(?:/\*)).*\s*.font-family:.*

Comment: Could you please check [my approach](https://regex101.com/r/pU0bB3/1)? I "ignore" font-family inside the comments, and remove all others, but I am not sure what the final output is required.

Comment: I have tried, thank you, it also finds other comments :)

Comment: As I said, it returns other results as well, including stuff wrapped in comments :)

Comment: Then please clarify with examples. In Boost syntax, you cannot use `(*SKIP)(*F)` verbs, you must match and capture. I find the question rather unclear now.

Comment: Ok, so I want to run a search that will find all `font-family:` strings not preceded by a comment tag.

So the search should return ALL lines containing `font-family:+WHATVER` but NOT return `/* font-family:+WHATVER`

Comment: Like [`^(?:(?!/\*).)*\s*font-family:.*`](https://regex101.com/r/pU0bB3/2)? I fixed your tempered greedy token.

Comment: Works awesome, all my upvotes are belong to you :) post it so I can chose it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost done it yourself, I just  fixed your [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
^(?:(?!/\*).)*\s*font-family:.*
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pU0bB3/2)

**Regex explanation**:

- `^` - start of line (in S&R in SublimeText)
- `(?:(?!/\*).)*` - a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) matching 0 or more characters other than a newline up to the first `/*` (to force a `.` to match newlines, add `(?s)` before `^`)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace symbols
- `font-family:`- a literal sequence of `font-family:`
- `.*` - 0 or more characters other than newline

Comment: Sorry, wife is grumbling too much, I will add explanations later.